# What piece has one prong on one end and four on the other?

Tags: part-identification

Yesterday I wanted to [answer a question](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/13212/which-parts-have-no-friction-technic-axle-holes/13213#comment15681_13212) with this part in mind, but I couldn't find it in any of the databases I looked in. After finding this part in my collection, I tried to look for its part number to properly reference it, but to no avail. What's more, there was no LEGO marking to be seen either. So now I'm really interested: is this even a real LEGO part?

The material, finish, precision seem all correct, and it fits in the LEGO system in various ways, which is atypical for clone brands.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ive always used it as a torch piece.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It is called [Plant, Tree Palm Top](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2566&name=Plant,%20Tree%20Palm%20Top&category=%5BPlant,%20Tree%5D#T=C). It used to be green or brown and was a part of the palm trees found in the Pirate kits. It was the part that the leaves joined onto. The four prongs pointed up.

[image: 1889 Palm Tree Build]

Comment: Thanks for sharing, and welcome to Bricks!

Comment: @zovits thanks for adding the pic

Comment: I have been trying to find this piece for ages but I can't look that piece up on Legos website. Is there anything else it could be called? I need this piece for a build I'm working on

Comment: @jacobmarshburn TLG calls it "ASSEMBLY ELEMENT Ø3.2". It's available via LEGO.com Bricks and Pieces in black, tan, and light bluish gray currently. It is available in many more colors on Bricklink.

Answer (score 18):

In a classic rubber duck moment, the solution has dawned on me minutes after asking the question, while browsing the list of sets owned by me to find the one that included this piece...

This is [ASSEMBLY ELEMENT Ø3.2 etc.](https://brickset.com/parts/design-2566) or with Bricklink terminology: [Plant, Tree Palm Top](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2566&name=Plant,%20Tree%20Palm%20Top&category=%5BPlant,%20Tree%5D#T=C):

[image]

The complete lack of markings of any kind is still puzzling, but it is reassuring that the part is indeed a genuine LEGO piece.

---

Update:

After finding a more recent part of the same design, it does indeed contain a LEGO marking on the upper edge, but the older one I found first does not. Curious.

[image]

Comment: It's a tree top? I always thought it was the handle of a torch of sorts.

Comment: @Mast It's been used as a torch in medieval sets (usually mounted to a wall, with a flame piece in the centre) but its first appearance (in [this set](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemPic.asp?S=6270-1), I think) was as a linkage to attach the four leaves of a palm tree to its flexible trunk.

Comment: This part is incredibly versatile. While it has limited utility as a decoration by itself, it can make all sorts of weird connections possible.

Comment: @Mast The beauty of LEGO is that this part is equally a torch, a tree top, a rocket, a four pronged barbecue skewer, a cage for a tiny animal, a miniature Eiffel Tower, a drill attachment, and countless other things, limited only by the imagination :)

Comment: It was used as a table-stand (upside down) in the Assembly Square set :)